# Alternative proof that $\mbox{tr}(A)$ is an eigenvalue of a rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof, trace

I had the an assignment to prove that $\mbox{tr}(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if $\mbox{rank}(A)=1$. I was able to prove it the following way:

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix such that $rankA=1$, then there exists a vector $v \in V$ so that every column of $A$ equals $cv$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. In that case, we assert that for every vector $u \in V$ the following occurs $Au = \sum_{i=1}^nu_ic_iv \in Sp\{v\}$. Therefore, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Now all that's left is to find that $Av=tr(A)v$ by working the indices.

Here is the problem: I rather dislike the proof, as it relies on "charging ahead" mindlessly with eigenvectors. Are there any alternative ways to prove this?

Comment: Hint: use $\text{tr}\{A\} = \lambda_1 + \ldots +\lambda_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $rank(A)=1 \implies\dim(N(A))=n-1$ then we have $n-1$ zero eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_{n-1}$ and $Tr(A)=\sum \lambda_i=\lambda_n$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming diagonizability? You know that the null space has dimension $n-1$, but how do you know there's an $n$-th eigenvalue?

Comment: I assume he uses the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = trA$, therefore if there are $n-1$ eigenvalues which are zero, then the last one has to be equal to $trA$.

Comment: @P.Diddy: You're also assuming diagonalizability; without that, the equation you write makes no sense, since there may not be $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: @joriki: True. I wonder if that can be "patched over" with the first part of my proof, saying "for every vector $u \in V$ the following occurs $Au = \sum_{i=1}^nu_ic_iv \in Sp\{v\}$". This means there is another, nonzero eigenvalue. Is that possible?

Comment: @joriki If $rank(A)=1$ $\dim(N(A))=n-1$ and thus we have $n-1$ distinct eigenvectors with $\lambda=0$ therefore $Tr(A)=\lambda$, where does diagonalization come into play? Could you exaplain better. Thanks

Comment: I think I see now the argument that you're implicitly using. You've shown that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is $n-1$, and its algebraic multiplicity is at least the geometric multiplicity; hence the algebraic multiplicity is at least $n-1$. The sum of the eigenvalues according to their algebraic multiplicities is the trace, and you don't need diagonalizability for that. I was confused by this implicit switch from geometric to algebraic multiplicities; I thought you were assuming that the geometric multiplicities add up to $n$.

Comment: @joriki yes exactly dim(N(A))=n-1 suffices to obtain directly the result since zero eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity at least equal to n-1

Answer (score 2):

The rank is $1$ implies that $Im(f)=Vect(v)$, where $f$ is the linear endomorphism whose matrix is $A$ in the canonical basis. let $(v,f_1,...,f_{n-1})$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A(v)=cv, A(f_i)=c_iv$,  the only non zero term of the matrix of $f$ in the basis $(v,f_1,..,f_{n-1})$ is $c$ this implies that $tr(A)=c$ since the trace does not depend of the basis.